# Peformance of universal selector, contradicting results?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, jquery-selectors

According to the official website:

> The all, or universal, selector is extremely slow, except when used by itself.

So, I think this means that `$("#section").find("*")` should be faster than `$("#section *")`. However, as you can see in [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KVRqeK) pen I receive contradictory results.
Am I understanding the statement correctly?

Edit:

There is also `$("#section").children()` at the bottom. If it was just about the function call, this one should have been slower too.

Comment: Could not make out anything out of this => _The all, or universal, selector is extremely slow, except when used by itself_

Comment: @Rayon Dabre: That statement can be simplified to "The universal selector is extremely slow, except when used by itself." I don't know why jQuery feels the need to give it another name.

Comment: I suspect it's saying that anything other than `$("*")` will be slow.

Comment: Not sure what you expected to codepen to show. You're probably not going to notice the slowness unless you're dealing with hundreds of elements.

Comment: @Barmar I have used a loop of around 10,000 cycles.

Comment: jsperf.com would be a better place to do a benchmark.

Comment: can't compare `children()` to `find('*')` . Totally different collection

Comment: @Barmar I have also used jsperf, changing both the complexity of DOM and the selectors I use. However, almost every result seemed to indicate that a selector in combination seems to be faster.

Comment: yeah, find() is slow, everyone knows that. try comparing without find()

Comment: @dandavis How do I compare it without find? I need to get to all elements somehow and I can't use the universal selector in combination in both test cases.

Comment: i find it faster to pass the desired root element as a 2nd parameter to $:  `$("*", section)`...

Comment: Is it still not a combination? I apologize but I am confused.

Comment: the diff is only 100ms/10000 anyway, focus on the parts that really matter.

Answer (score -1):

`$("#section").find("*")` - two function calls.
`$("#section *")` - one call.

Function calls are pretty expensive in JS.

Comment: What does this have to do with the universal selector specifically?

Comment: I doubt this is the only reason!